# Where has MS Agent gone on in SQL Server Managment Studio I downloaded

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, t-sql, timer

I spent two years writing an automated betting BOT before my company outsourced all our servers we were hosting to OVH a French company and like many European countries for some reason they don't allow their country men to access online betting sites.

So therefore just as my BOT was ready to roll after a few months of testing with the Betfair API on £2 bets that made me £1,500 I was in a hole as any calls out from the OVH server returned a 404 message or some other status code that said access to this site from your IP address is not allowed.

I asked about proxies but then that would just double the amount of bandwidth we would be paying due to passing lots of JSON through two computers and back again.

Therefore I have downloaded my BOT code to my laptop and I have also installed the latest free VS Studio version as well as SQL Server Management Studio. I am hoping to get it working on my laptop before changing it into a Windows Form App I can sell.

So question 1: for some reason I can only login on my laptop using my Windows Username e.g HP/[my name] with no need for a password.

Is this correct? As if I look at the connection string on the server it is a standard connection string SERVER, DATABASE, USER, PASSWORD e.g

```
PROVIDER=SQLOLEDB; SERVER=LOCALHOST; DATABASE=BettingBOT; uid=bettingBOT; pwd=bettingBOTc100x1;
```

I am not sure when running SQL Server Management Studio on my laptop whether I should be using a different connection string from when it worked on a server and if I have to use the Windows one with HP/[my name] what would the connection string from the app to the DB be and what login should I use to open up ALL databases in MS Studio so I can see them all?

Question 2: I cannot find the C# CLR Code (I left my company), that enabled me to write a DLL with one class in it containing 2 methods for Regular Expressions. I have lost the original class (probably still at work) and I know what to do to install the CLR, test it and where to place the DLL's but I just cannot find the C# class with the 2 regular expressions in and the format, as they had a special kind of keyword in their naming that I cannot remember that allows SQL Server to use the C# code when running a UDF that points to it. Any useful links would be appreciated. I am sure it not protected as I am overwriting the normal process, just can't seem to remember what I wrote.

Question 3: if I run this code in SQL Server Management Studio on my laptop I get this return..

```
SELECT  @@version,
SELECT  SERVERPROPERTY ('productversion'),
SELECT  SERVERPROPERTY ('productlevel'),
SELECT  SERVERPROPERTY ('edition')
```

I get these results...

Version:

```
Microsoft SQL Server 2017 (RTM) - 14.0.1000.169 (X64)   Aug 22 2017 17:04:49   
Copyright (C) 2017 Microsoft Corporation Express Edition (64-bit) 
on Windows 8.1 6.3 <X64> (Build 9600: ) 

Product Version:    14.0.1000.169
Product Level:      RTM
Edition:            Express Edition (64-bit)
```

I know the size is going to be limited as its a free version and I've come down from an Enterprise Edition with unlimited size so I am going to have to trim my code back a bit. What is the database size limit for a system like the one those values show? Do I have a limit on growth, initial size, growth size, memory, CPU etc?

Question 4: I don't have MS Agent on SQL Server 2017. At the bottom of the tree I have something called XEventProfiler where MS Agent used to be. Does MS SQL not have MS Agent anymore or do I have to re-install it and select something I might have missed OR do I need to install and load it separately into SQL Server Management Studio?

I just have never worked on 2017 before and the old DB was on 2012 and had MS Agent, I have tried changing the version numbers of the DBs but that does nothing.

Does anyone know how I can get MS Agent installed or will I have to use Windows Task Manager to run timed stored procedures or use timers in my code to replace MS Agent jobs. Its just I had jobs that ran at night to refresh stats, profit/loss, load in new records and so on. So there will be a lot of new timers in my BOTs Service which it is run from.

I will either have to run these START and STOP jobs that used to run automatically at the end of the day to when the person hit the "Open BOT" button and then again when they hit "Close BOT" down and then use progress bars to show how long its taking.

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance for any help received. Or any useful links you can find please pass them on.

Comment: Agent is not included in Express.

Comment: maybe a TL - DR - it was too long. SQL Agent comes with Dev, Std and Enterprise sku's. You may be in luck if you have installed SQL Engine (Dev, Std, or Ent) and have accidentally downloaded the SQL Management Studio express edition.

Comment: where is the duplicate answer then as when I typed in my question heading nothing of relevance popped up otherwise I would have read it. Where is the link. Also if no MS Agent comes with Express what is the best replacement method using timers in my C# front end with Start/Stop buttons to run the jobs OR Windows Task Manager to run the procs or build the timers to run them into the core app, just mean that the PC would have 2 stay open and running long after finishing betting for all jobs 2 run. Wanted behind the scene jobs running. Any alternative apart from these?